# Parse command output with awk and count results

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I have an output from the 'multipath -ll' command

From RHEL:

```
mpath114 (3600507680283095ea8000000000004fa) dm-28 IBM,2145
[size=200G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 19:0:0:40 sdea 128:32  [active][ready]
 \_ 20:0:1:40 sdeb 128:48  [active][ready]
 \_ 20:0:1:41 sdec 128:16  [failed][faulty]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 20:0:0:40 sdba 67:64   [active][ready]
 \_ 19:0:1:40 sdgg 131:192 [active][ready]
mpath131 (3600507680283095ea800000000000504) dm-39 IBM,2145
[size=10G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 20:0:1:1  sdbl 67:240  [active][ready]
 \_ 19:0:0:1  sdc  8:32    [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 19:0:1:1  sdet 129:80  [active][ready]
 \_ 20:0:0:1  sdk  8:160   [active][ready]
[..]
```

Or from SLES server:

```
mpathmzp (36005076801c7061ef800000000000089) dm-0 IBM,2145
size=10G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=50 status=enabled
| `- 67:0:2:0 sde 8:64 active ready running
| `- 68:0:0:1 sdl 8:76 failed faulty running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=10 status=enabled
  |- 67:0:3:0 sdc 8:32 active ready running
  `- 68:0:0:0 sdd 8:48 active ready running
[..]
```

I would like to parse it (preferably with awk or bash), to display summary of the configuration.
It should print the pseudo multipath device and the number of active paths and the failed (if any)
Sample:

```
dm-39, 10G,  Total: 4 paths, active: 4, failed: 0
dm-28, 200G, Total: 5 paths, active: 4, failed: 1
```

Same for the SLES:

```
dm-0,  10G,  Total: 4 paths, active: 3, failed: 1
```

If also possible, I'd like to sort the output so that the paths with no failed and most active paths are on top, and end with the devicess with the failed paths.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Let's see your, my be not working, script ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
multipath -ll | awk 'NR>1 {r=f=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/ready/) r++; else if ($i~/faulty/) f++;split($5,a,"=|]");print $3,a[2]"\tTotal: "r+f" paths, active: "r,"failed: "f}' RS="mpath" OFS=", "
dm-28, 200G     Total: 5 paths, active: 4, failed: 1
dm-39, 10G      Total: 4 paths, active: 4, failed: 0
```

Comment: I've noticed that some systems the size isn't in the 5th field. How can I use it dynamically?